# Linq Top, Group By and Order By

Tags: c#, linq

Could you help me convert this SQL statement to Linq?
I have done an IN before but the GROUP BY, ORDER BY and TOP are parts I haven't done before.

```
SELECT TOP 300 lower(UserName) FROM UserHistory
WHERE LOWER(UserName) IN (SELECT Lower(UserName) FROM ActiveUsers)
GROUP BY LOWER(UserName)
ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC
```

Comment: Really, you should at least show the attempts you've made, suggest why they didn't work / what errors you got, and ideally reference any sites / examples / documentation you've looked at and couldn't use.

Comment: Linq-to-sql, Entity Framework, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY is done in Linq by:

```
group 'result here' by 'field here'
```

ORDER BY is done in Linq by:

```
.OrderBy('lambda expression here')
```

or

```
orderby //field here  ascending | descending
```

TOP is done in Linq by:

```
.Take('number here');
```

NOTE: the arguments are not strings, just a way to say you have to put the correct value there.

Comment: try -->    .OrderBY(x=> x.Max(x.date))